# mod_rewrite, old URLs to new URLs

Tags: mod-rewrite

Migrating a site and trying to preserve some bookmarks and search results

Old URL

```
topic/0/14.php
```

New URL

```
Module/news/filter/topic^sub^10282/page1.htm
```

Seems like this should be pretty straightforward, and I've tried but

```
RewriteRule ^topic/0/14\.php /Module/news/filter/topic^sub^10282/page1.htm? [R=301,L]
```

results in a redirect that goes to

```
example.com/home/example/domains/public_html/Module/news/filter/topic^sub^10282/page1.htm
```

... in other words, the redirect contains the full URI, not from the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `RewriteBase /`?

Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase .

Mike.

Comment: Not sure why this is necessary, since both paths are at document root, and all my other mod_rewrites are working.